# block submitting forms that are not from a specific domain

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have an online game site, that submits users' records and displays them in site score board.
But, some users like to be #1 (!) and they create a form with my "action" and "method" forms that are for submitting.

Here is my form:

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post" id="form">
<input type="hidden" id="time" name="time">
<input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name']; ?>">
</form>
```

And here is js that runs at the end of the game:

```
document.getElementById("time").value=finaltime;
document.getElementById("form").submit();
```

"submit.php" inserts $_POST['time'] and $_POST['name'] into mysql database.

So, How can I prevent users to submit their own created form?
In another meaning, how can I find the origin of the submitted form in "submit.php" ?

Comment: Sounds like you need to redesign your server-side system.  Users should not be able to insert records by tricking your JavaScript.

Comment: But how? If I knew the origin of the submitted form, it would be awesome!

Comment: By using "sessions".  Only a logged in user should be authenticated to do anything like that on your site.  And your backend system should be sophisticated enough to know if the data is valid.  In any case, to fully explain how sessions work, etc. is too broad for the SO Q & A format.

Comment: I just find out the answer: NEVER make an HTML5 games with record submitting!

Comment: That's not the answer.  The answer is to properly use the available programming technologies.

Answer (score 0):

As far I as I am aware, there's no way to tell from which domain a record has been inserted into a database, unless the webpage passes that information when inserting. However, people aren't able to just insert into a database, if that's your concern. when they connect to the database they should require a username and password first (assuming you have that set-up). Here's how PHP connects to a database:

```
mysqli_connect("domain.com","username_here","password_here","database_here");
```

Even then, they still need to provide which table to insert the information into.

Comment: I know that. People submit their own time by their own forms (maybe the form are in their desktop!) and my "submit.php" file connects to database and insert that time as their record. I want to prevent submitting forms that are not my form in game page.

Comment: If you're asking the OP to contact you privately for more help, that sort of thing is not allowed on SO.  Your posted answer should be fully self-contained so that it benefits everyone.

Comment: Unfortunately, you've lost me a little bit here. People won't be able to connect to your database at all without usernames and passwords etc.. Right? Unless you tell people that information, then there's no way for them to connect. So the only way people could is through your form. It's practically impossible to do connect without knowing the required info. If this doesn't answer your question, please give me some more context on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Sparky Thanks Sparky. Although I mean for the OP to comment, I'll refrain from asking such again. Thanks again, Xanco.

Comment: You know everyone can make a form and submit it to a destination. right? And my "submit.php" , insert the submitted values into a db that just I know the username and password of that. Ok, so people can submit their own records.